# What really makes a Dialog window behave as a modal dialog?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, documentation, dialog-window

```
CreateDialog[DefaultButton[], Modal -> True]
```

creates a modal `Dialog`, one which needs to be closed before the front-end becomes available for further interaction.

Very useful. However

```
CreateDialog[DefaultButton[], Modal -> True, WindowFrame -> "ThinFrame"]
```

creates a `Dialog` which is not modal despite the `Modal` option being given.

Why does this happen? What really determines that a dialog is modal?

---

*keywords*: FrontEnd, block, Dialog, Window, WindowFrame

---

Reported to WRI. Will keep you informed.

> [CASE:2559336] Feedback/ Dialogs documentation status:
>
> [...] I have forwarded a report of this to the appropriate people in our development team with the information you provided and included your contact information. [...] I have included a comment about modifying the documentation to give more explanation, as well. [...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What really makes `Dialog` a model dialog is:

```
WindowFrame -> "ModalDialog" 

(*or*)

WindowFrame -> "MovableModalDialog"
```

So be careful when changing `WindowFrame` with the expectation that your dialog will remain modal.

---

Funny proof is that the following:

```
CreateDialog[DefaultButton[], WindowFrame -> "ModalDialog", Modal -> False]
```

**is** a modal dialog.

---

I think this is useful info. The *Mathematica* tutorials and guides concerning `Dialog` do not say anything about this matter.

Comment: I indeed urge you to report this as a defect in the documentation.

Comment: @m_goldberg done

Comment: +1 Looks like either a bug or a design oversight