# Notebooks created after prompting a Modal dialog

Tags: bugs, front-end, windows, dialog-window

**Bug reproduced in 10.3.1 and persisting through 11.2.0**

---

From:

> Note: `Modal` dialogs will prevent users from accessing **other notebooks in the front end while the dialog is open**. If there is no mechanism for closing the dialog, the Wolfram System will effectively freeze.
>
> tutorial/CreatingDialogBoxes

But try to evaluate this code: (all at once)

```
CreateDialog[{TextCell["ordinary 1"], DefaultButton[]}, 
 WindowMargins -> 100]

CreateDialog[{TextCell["modal"], DefaultButton[]}, Modal -> True, 
 WindowMargins -> 200]

CreateDialog[{TextCell["ordinary 2"], DefaultButton[]}, 
 WindowMargins -> 300]
```

Both "ordinary" dialogs are expected to be frozen till the Modal one is closed.
It's not the case on Windows. Works correctly on Mac OS though.

I don't think documentation leaves any room for exceptions, right?

---

Related: [What really makes a Dialog expresion behave as a modal dialog?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75969/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3620463] was created.

And a reply:

> [...] I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided.