# What is the Kernel waiting for after DialogInput is launched?

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, dialog-window, scheduling

**Bug introduced in 11.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.2**

> [...] I was able to reproduce the issue, and consequently, I filed a report with our development team [...]
>
> CASE:3805351

---

I find this behavior unexpected and I would like to ask whether it is only me who thinks it is a bug.

#### The case

It seems that `MessageDialog` and `CreateDialog` windows are interfering with kernel blocking dialogs (e.g. `DialogInput`) on `WindowClose` event of one of formers. E.g. please create those 3 dialogs:

```
CreateWindow @ DialogNotebook["regular dialog (CreateDocument), close it first"]

CreateDialog["regular dialog, close it as a second", 
 WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}]

DialogInput["kernel blocking dialog waiting for input", 
 WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 200}}]
```

After that the kernel is waiting for `DialogInput` response. But before that let's close other notebooks.

The manually created one (`CreateWindow`) does nothing but exiting `CreateDialog` makes the `Kernel` to think that it was the `DialogInput` one - `$Failed` is returned.

Which is unexpected and makes `MessageDialog/CreateDialog` too unstable. Every kernel blocking dialog can also be a FrontEnd blocking one (`Modal -> True`) but it won't save us completely as there is another bug related to dialogs: [Notebooks created after prompting a Modal dialog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116584/5478)

#### Investigation

I believe it is caused by:

```
"WindowClose" :> (FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton[]];
   DialogReturn[$Failed])
```

which is inserted to all higher level dialog functions like `MessageDialog`.

#### Question

Already reported, but what do you think, is it expected, is there a good reason behind that?